# How to remove CASE statements from my results?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, case

I am writing a query to return some info, but the stored procedure wont return the results in the page because the values dont match the table definition. i understand this error. but i'm using the case statement to filtering based off a field (whether the t.TimeCallWasReceived is received or not). when i do this, it allows for the sp to run while either the user checking the db for changes or using signalR to detect db changes. I dont want the CASE statement to be a part of my results. i know i can alter the page or the temp table, but i want to know if there is anything i can do in t-sql to return the results without the case statement in said results. the query is below.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.Num,
       'Notified for pickup ' + (CONVERT(varchar(30), c.ServiceCalled, 100)) + '. Number ' + c.Num AS Issue,
       RTRIM(c.NameFirst) + ' ' + RTRIM(c.NameLast) AS CusName,
       (CASE
             WHEN t.TimeCallWasReceived IS NULL THEN CONVERT(varchar(20), t.TimeCallWasReceived, 113)
             ELSE 'NO'
        END) AS CallReceivedAt
FROM tblCustomer c
     LEFT JOIN tblTransportation t ON t.Num = c.Num
WHERE t.TimeCallWasReceived IS NULL
  AND c.Type = 'Type1'
  AND c.ServiceCalled IS NOT NULL
  AND c.TransportNum IS NULL
  AND LEFT(c.Num, 2) <> 'CR'
  AND LEFT(c.Num, 2) <> 'TR'
  AND (c.Status <> 'Void'
    OR c.Status <> 'Closed')
  AND ((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, c.ServiceCalled, GETDATE())) > 180)
  AND c.Type <> 'VOID'
  AND c.Type <> 'NON'
  AND c.Type <> 'Walk-In'
  AND c.Type <> 'CFR'
  AND c.CaseType <> 'PAP'
  AND c.ServiceCalled >= DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())
ORDER BY c.Num DESC;
```

Comment: FYI, it's a `CASE` **expression**, not a `CASE` statement.

Comment: `IIF (t.TimeCallWasReceived IS NULL, CONVERT(varchar(20), t.TimeCallWasReceived, 113), 'NO') AS CallReceivedAt`

Comment: I don't really understand what you're after here. If you don't want the column defined by the `CASE` expression in the results, then remove it from the `SELECT`. Why can't you do that?

Comment: That's still, technically, a `CASE` expression "under the hood", @squillman ;)

Comment: Side note, using functions like `DATEDIFF` or `LEFT` on your columns in the `WHERE` make it non-SARGable, which is bad for performance. You should be using `DATEADD` on `GETDATE()` and a `LIKE` expression respectively.

Comment: Also you can remove all those `<>` clauses on `c.Type`. The second clause in your `WHERE` is `c.Type = 'Type1'` so it would be *literally* impossible for it's value to be `'VOID'` or any of the other values. If you *did* need all those `<>` clauses (you don't here) why not `NOT IN`?

Comment: Actually, why do you have `((DATEDIFF(MINUTE, c.ServiceCalled, GETDATE())) > 180)` and `c.ServiceCalled >= DATEADD(DAY, -2, GETDATE())` as well..? That's like having `WHERE MyCol > 15 AND MyCol > 5`. The second clause is pointless and the former is more restrictive.

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, well...  Same execution plan but technically does get rid of the `CASE` :)  In case OP was just looking for something syntacitcally different.

Comment: Yeah, honestly, I smell a larger over arching problem after looking at that `WHERE`, @squillman .

Comment: RE: "*...but the stored procedure wont return the results in the page because the values dont match the table definition...*"  This statement is pretty confusing, what "*the page*" and what "*the table*" are you talking about?  It's like there's a whole paragraph of explanation/context before this that got lost.

Comment: The condition is wrong anyway `WHEN t.TimeCallWasReceived IS NULL` you cannot convert it and should probably return `'NO'` in this case.

Comment: Well, technically speaking, you *can* `CONVERT` a date and time data type with the value `NULL` to a `varchar`, @OlivierJacot-Descombes , just it's value will still be `NULL`.  Though you are correct, as the `CASE` expression will either return `NULL` or `'NO'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
--1. Since the WHERE clause has `t.TimeCallWasReceived IS NULL`, you will see only ---'NO' in the CallReceivedAt result column.
--2. Since the WHERE clause has `c.Type = 'Type1'`, it makes unnecessary to look for 

c.Type <> 'VOID'
c.Type <> 'NON'
c.Type <> 'Walk-In'
c.Type <> 'CFR'

--because they are exclusive for the rest of the values different than 'Type1'.
--3. I don't see a way to get rid of the CASE
--    Perhaps you like this way better:
    
CASE ISNULL(t.TimeCallWasReceived, '')
     WHEN '' THEN CONVERT(varchar(20), t.TimeCallWasReceived, 113)
             ELSE 'NO'
END
```

Comment: another hit and run